# Log4net Configuration with referenced library

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration

Apologies for another log4net configuration question.
I have a referenced library that has this method:

```
public static ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass));
public void InitializeLog()
{
    XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("log4net.xml"));
    Logger.Info("Starting");
}
```

In the project that uses this DLL, I have the log4net.xml at the root level of the project. It looks like this:

```
<log4net>
  <logger name="NHibernate">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
  </logger>
  <logger name="NHibernate.SQL">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
  </logger>
  <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date %level - %message%newline%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\log\project.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10000KB" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <footer value ="&#13;&#10;"/>
      <conversionPattern value="%date %level - %message%newline%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

The project calls `InitializeLog()` before it ever tries to log anything. However, it won't even log the "Starting" message at the beginning. When I debug the method, in the Logger object I see `Configured = false`. I have a feeling it has something to do with the path to the xml file, because it works fine in a project that uses this library as project reference instead of an external one (not an option here.) Thoughts as to why the configuration fails.?

Comment: Is the log4net.xml file marked as "Copy to Output Directory"? (You can check the FileInfo's `Exists` property to see if it picks it up)

Comment: @stuartd, yeah it's set to Copy always

Comment: Could be anything. Use the linked question to find your error.

Answer (score 0):

log4net search config in current folder. You need to specify full path to config file:

ASP.NET application

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...
        string l4net = Server.MapPath("~/log4net.config");
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo(l4net));
    }
```

WinForm or Console application:

1. In Solution Explorer right click on log4net.config, select Properties and set Copy to Output Directory - Copy if newer
2. Use full path to Output Directory (you can call your exe from another folder)

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       var appPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
       log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo(appPath));
   }
   ```

Content of my log4net.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="osai.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <encoding value="utf-8" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <maximumFileSize value="50MB" />
      <immediateFlush value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="Header" value="--- Application start ---&#xD;&#xA;" />
        <param name="Footer" value="--- Application stop ---&#xD;&#xA;" />
        <conversionPattern value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What's the full namespace for Server? VS is giving me a few options to pick.

Comment: It is Asp.Net namespace System.Web. See answer update for WinForm or Console application.

Comment: no luck for either of those.

Comment: than your config is invalid. add my config to answer.